# How do I view any file in Qt's TreeView?

Tags: c++, qt, qfilesystemmodel

Currently, I have this code:

```
QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel();
sc_me->ui->treeView_2->setAnimated(true);
sc_me->ui->treeView_2->setSortingEnabled(true);
sc_me->ui->treeView_2->setModel(model);
sc_me->ui->treeView_2->setRootIndex(model->index(webSite));
```

And it will only let me view directories leading up to the directory that the file is being run in, so if it's being run in `c:/directory1/directory2`, I can't view `c:/dir42`, only `c:/directory1/directory2/`

Comment: And what would be `model->index(webSite)`? Maybe it is incorrect and resorts to default path, which is application working directory?

Comment: I've tried a variety of directories. It shows the directory if it's a parent directory or a sub directory, but that's it.